# Route Overlapping in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-5.6

I've two following routes:

```
Route::name('frontend-')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{category}/{slug}', 'GetFrontendController@tourDetail')->name('tourDetail');
    Route::get('/{pcatslug}/{pslug}','GetFrontendController@getPage')->name('page');
});
```

The route name `page` is overlapping with the route name `tourDetail`. When I try to access the route `page`  `tourDetail` function is being envoked as the route `tourDetail` is declared first.

I tried putting them in different named group and applied regex pattern still couldn't resolve this issue.

Regex pattern I've applied are:

```
Route::pattern('category', '[A-Za-z\d\-\_]+');
Route::pattern('slug','[A-Za-z\d\-\_]+');
Route::pattern('pcatslug', '[A-Za-z\d\-\_]+');
Route::pattern('slug','[A-Za-z\d\-\_]+');
```

How can I overcome this route overlapping issue. Please suggest.

Comment: they are the same exact URI pattern (2 wildcards `"*/*"`), they are always going to overlap one another. There is no difference between these 2 in that regard. changing the order will just change which overlaps which.

Comment: So, i guess this issue will stick with Laravel till eternity

Comment: its not an issue with Laravel, it is an issue with your routes .. forget wildcards:  `get /something` and another route `get /something` ... how is that conflict supposed to be resolved? how could you possibly differentiate between them?

Answer (score 1):

This will not work, because the router template specifies the same one pattern. To ensure that the router system does not redefine the routes, you must either change the pattern or add a static part with an individual name to the URL, for example:

```
Route::get('categories/{category}/{slug}',   'GetFrontendController@tourDetail')->name('tourDetail');

Route::get('pcatslugs/{pcatslug}/{pslug}','GetFrontendController@getPage')->name('page');
```